# Property setter type other value set to property?

Tags: c#

It is possible for the type returning by a property's `get` accessor to be different from the type used by the `set` accessor?

```
private string[] artists;
public string[] Artists
{
    get { return artists[0]; } //heree getter return string than string[]
    set { artists = value; OnPropertyChanged("Artist"); }
}
```

Comment: Note that `OnPropertyChanged("Artist")` does not match he property name here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this won't work.

You could add another property, and include it in the ONPC:

```
public string Artist
{
    get { return artists[0]; }
}

public string[] Artists
{
    // get { return artists; }   // get string[] is optional
    set { artists = value; OnPropertyChanged("Artist"); OnPropertyChanged("Artists");}
}
```

Provide a sample of intended use with some context and you  might get a better answer.

Comment: your code makes it possible to get to the value set by the setter. OPs code does not. Itøs hard to tell whether or not this is part of the intention of course since the intention is not documented. Leaving out the get on artists would be closer to OPs code in my opinion. (Also thinking OP might be unaware that you can have a write only property this might be important or unimportant if my guess is off :) )

Comment: @Rune: Possible, it's hard to picture the use here. That's why I asked for some context.

Comment: I totally agree. I mainly wrote the comment to high light that it was possible (though usually weird) to emit the getter

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible. You have to create another property to return another type.

Answer (score 0):

Why should this be possible. If you declare the return type then this HAS to be returned.

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible. It is plain to see that your code is illegal, because your get accessor does not fulfil it's obligation to return a `string[]`

```
// you define the Artists property as a string[],
// therefore the get accessor must return a string[]
public string[] Artists
{
    // you are returning only a string
    get { return artists[0]; }
```